# ¿como puedo renderizar una variable que exporte con una funcion externa en react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Estoy realizando un sitio web de una tienda virtual de gorras, para mi universidad, actualmente en la vista principal uso una libreria llamada SplitPane para dividir la vista de la pantalla en dos, mi vista izquierda me muestra los productos mientras mi vista derecha me muestra un mensaje por defecto el cual es (Seleccione un producto para editarlo o precione el boton de agregar producto) que se encuentra en la segunda fraccion del codigo, pero al clickear lo, no me cambia al componente formulario para agregar, ya intenten darle un valor statico y funciona correctamente, pero el error es que la vista derecha no me renderiza de nuevo (segunda fraccion de codigo), realmente no se que hacer e intentado renderizar lo de muchas formas y no me funciona la vercion de react que estoy utilizando es la 18 agradeceria su ayuda.
el sitio web que utilice para ese estilo es de uber eats (https://django.fun/en/qa/126/) la segunda imagen es la que contiene la forma visual que tengo de las pantallas divididas y el boton.

tengo un archivo jsx (vista izquierda)el cual cuenta con dos funciones

```
import React from 'react'

import AddIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Add';
import Producto from './AdminProducto'
import '../stylesheets/AdminIzq.css'
import { useState} from 'react'

export function Changebool() {
        let [bool, setBool] = useState(false);
        console.log(bool);
        const Change=()=>{
            setBool(!bool);
            console.log(bool);
            return bool;
        }
        return Change;
}


export function AdminIzq() {

    return (
        <>
        <header>
            <div className="contenedor-admin-izq-header">
                <div className="contenedor-admin-izq-tittle">
                    <div className="admin-izq">
                        <button onClick={Changebool()} id="bool"><AddIcon />Agregar</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </header>
        <main>
            <div className="contenedor-admin-izq">
                <Producto
                imagen='adidas-gris'
                titulo= 'Gorra Adidas Gris Oscuro'
                descripcion='Gorra ADIDAS de la mejor calidad color gris oscuro y con excelente materiales de fabricacion'
                precio='119.900'
                />
                <Producto
                imagen='adidas-negro'
                titulo= 'Gorra Adidas Negro'
                descripcion='Gorra ADIDAS de la mejor calidad color negro con los mejores materiales de fabricacion'
                precio='199.900'
                />
                <Producto
                imagen='creeper-verde'
                titulo= 'Gorra Creeper color verde'
                descripcion='Gorra con cara de Creeper(minecraft) color verde con excelente calidad'
                precio='79900'
                />
                <Producto
                imagen='adidas-gris'
                titulo= 'Gorra color gris'
                descripcion='Gorra de color gris con los mejores materiales de fabricacion brindando una comodidad excelente'
                precio='69900'
                />
                <Producto
                imagen='LA-azul'
                titulo= 'Gorra de color azul oscuro'
                descripcion='Gorra de color azul oscuro de excelente calidad'
                precio='69900'
                />
            </div>
        </main>
        </>
    );
}
```

cuento con otro archivo jsx (vista derecha) el cual tiene un condicional para mostrar me un componoente que es el siguiente

```
import React, { Component, useEffect } from 'react';

import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';

import AgregarProduc from './AgregarProduc';
import {Changebool} from './AdminIzq';

function AdminDerec() {
    return class extends React.Component {
        render() {
            return (
                <div>
                    {Changebool() ? <AgregarProduc /> : <h1>Seleccione un producto para editarlo o precione el boton de agregar producto</h1>}
                </div>
            );
        }
    }
}

export default AdminDerec;
```

Mi principal problema y duda, es si me encuentro renderizando la vista de forma erronea o si hay una forma de renderizar el valor que traigo de la funcion, la funcion se me renderiza pero a la hora que cambia su valor, cambia el valor en la funcion pero no cambia en el segundo jsx

Comment: Por qué combinas componentes funcionales con componentes de clase? Te recomiendo que leas la documentación oficial de react para que tengas una base sobre el renderizado https://es.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html

Comment: Qué pretendes lograr con la función `function Changebool()`? Cuál es tu idea?

Comment: Me parece que tienes un enfoque algo confuso en cuanto a la función que cambia el valor bool, da la impresion de que quieres tener un hook personalizado.

Answer (score 0):

Después de revisar tu código y teniendo en cuenta la premisa "*al clickear lo, no me cambia al componente formulario para agregar*" he confeccionado esta sugerencia:

Comentas que tienes una vista principal en la cual haces uso del componente SplitPane para dividir la pantalla en 2 partes, una para AdminDerecho y otra para AdminIzquierdo.

Si tienes un componente principal por que no crear una variable de estado en ese componente y pasarlo como propiedad a los demás componentes, por ejemplo:

```js
export default function App() {
  const [bool, setBool] = useState(false);

  return (
    <div className="container">
      <SplitPane split="vertical">
        <AdminIzq bool={bool} setBool={setBool} />
        <AdminDer bool={bool} />
      </SplitPane>
    </div>
  );
}
```

En el código anterior empleamos las variables de estado `[bool, setBool]` las cuales pasamos a los componentes como `props`, `<AdminIzq bool={bool} setBool={setBool} />`

Y solo quedaría utilizar dichos valores en cada uno de tus componentes:

- **AdminIzq**:

```js
export function AdminIzq(props) {
    const {bool, setBool} = props;
    return (
        <>
        <header>
            <div className="contenedor-admin-izq-header">
                <div className="contenedor-admin-izq-tittle">
                    <div className="admin-izq">
                        <button onClick={() => setBool(!bool)} id="bool"><AddIcon />Agregar</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </header>
        <main>
            <div className="contenedor-admin-izq">
                <Producto
                imagen='adidas-gris'
                titulo= 'Gorra Adidas Gris Oscuro'
                descripcion='Gorra ADIDAS de la mejor calidad color gris oscuro y con excelente materiales de fabricacion'
                precio='119.900'
                />
            </div>
        </main>
        </>
    );
}
```

- **AdminDec**:

```js
function AdminDerec(props) {
  const {bool} = props;
  return (
    <div>
      {bool ? (
        <AgregarProduc />
      ) : (
        <h1>
          Seleccione un producto para editarlo o precione el boton de agregar
          producto
        </h1>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}
```

En ambos componentes acceso a la propiedad haciendo *destructuring* `const {bool, setBool} = props;` y luego lo utilizo:

- `<button onClick={() => setBool(!bool)} id="bool"><AddIcon />Agregar</button>`
- `bool ?`

Te dejo un pequeño [playground](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ubywp7?file=src/App.js) basándome en tu ejemplo (Puede que no sea el mismo, pero la idea es que veas la funcionalidad).

**PD**: TU componente AdminDerec estaba escrito de manera incorrecta ya que utilizabas logica de un componente de clase dentro de un componente funcional.